# Error in converting varchar to float in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have imported a large Excel spreadsheet into my SQL Server database and all the columns are by default of `varchar` datatype. I have `NULL` values also in my columns (`sale` column). I want to select `sale volume` as `float (double)` which is in `varchar` format.

My query is as follows but I am still getting a conversion error.

```
SELECT
    [CompanyCode] AS 'Company Code',
    [Sitecode] AS 'Site Code',
    [Product] AS 'Product Name',
    '' AS 'Tank ID',
    CONVERT(DATE, [InvDay]) AS Date,
    CAST([Sales] AS DECIMAL) AS 'Sale Volume',
    '' AS 'Record ID'
FROM
    [dbo].[2019-01]
```

Comment: Are you sure you have all the values in decimal format? To overcome this error try using Try_cast and give precision on decimal (such as Try_CAST([Sales] as decimal(10,5)) to avoid losing any decimal value and Try_Cast will take care of any conversion error by converting it to nulls

Comment: @Avi thanks I provided my updated query as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my query as follows and it works..

```
select 
        [CompanyCode] as 'Company Code',
        [Sitecode] as 'Site Code',
        [Product] as 'Product Name',
        '' as 'Tank ID',
        CONVERT(date, [InvDay]) as  Date,

        SaleV=(CASE
                    WHEN [Sales] ='NULL' THEN 0
                     WHEN [Sales] = '' then 0
                    ELSE
                     CONVERT(decimal(10,4) ,[Sales] )
                     END)


    FROM [dbo].[2018-01]
```

Comment: try_cast would do the same / similar without a case statement

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - Modified your query. Used IsNull() function to handle Null value.

```
select 
        [CompanyCode] as 'Company Code',
        [Sitecode] as 'Site Code',
        [Product] as 'Product Name',
        '' as 'Tank ID',
        CONVERT(date, [InvDay]) as  Date,
        CAST(ISNULL([Sales],0) as decimal(10,2)) as 'Sale Volume',
        '' as 'Record ID'
From [dbo].[2019-01]
```

Note: The above query will return 0.00 in case of null and will give error in case of string. to handle string value use the below query, the below query will return 0.00 in case of string or NULL otherwise convert into the decimal

```
select 
        [CompanyCode] as 'Company Code',
        [Sitecode] as 'Site Code',
        [Product] as 'Product Name',
        '' as 'Tank ID',
        CONVERT(date, [InvDay]) as  Date,
        ISNULL(TRY_CAST([Sales] as decimal(10,2)), 0) as 'Sale Volume',
        '' as 'Record ID'
From [dbo].[2019-01]
```